# If you are running php-from does tuning the apache mpm still do anything?

Tags: php-fpm, apache2, php56

So I switched to php 5.6 with fpm. I see there are now only 4 apache processes but about 400 php-fpm56 processes.

I've been tuning the php-fpm process (to little effect) by playing with the pm.xxxxx variables.

But I'm curious, should I still try to tune the http-mpm files that contain variables like Maxclients, maxworkers, etc or does that not have any effect and all the tuning should be focused on pm.xxxx variables for the php-fpm processes

Thanks!  If any of this is confusing or my terminology is confusing let me know. Still trying to wrap my head around this new way of doing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tune the Apache MPM variables, but in this configuration they only affect Apache itself. They have no effect on php-fpm. It has its own analogous set of variables to tune, as you've already discovered. If you aren't having an issue with Apache itself, there probably isn't any point to trying to tune them. (BTW, you should be using the mod_event MPM only, otherwise you gain no real benefit to using php-fpm.)